# ipython import error for gnome-keyring, but no import errors in *standard* python console

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, python-keyring

I'm trying to import gnomekeyring in ipython, but it's giving me the following error:

```
<ipython-input-3-8e3631b2d189> in <module>()
----> 1 import gnomekeyring as gk

ImportError: could not import gobject (could not find _PyGObject_API object)
```

The import works fine when I'm in the *standard* python console. All the functions work as expected. How would I debug this problem?

Comment: It sounds like ipython and your standard Python interpreter might be using different versions of Python. What are the versions that you see when you start these interpreters?

Comment: When invoking python, it shows python version 2.7.10 and ipython 2.3.0. When invoking python, it shows python 2.7.10.